# Prove that $(1-t^6)^6 = \sum_{j=0}^{6} {6 \choose j} (-1)^jt^{6j} $ using the binomial theorem

Tags: binomial-theorem

Show that 
$$(1-t^6)^6 = \sum_{j=0}^{6} {6 \choose j} (-1)^jt^{6j} $$

Using the binomial theorem $(x+y)^n = \sum_{j=0}^{n} {n \choose k} x^{n-k} y^{k}$, I get $$ \text{Let } \\x = 1 \\y = (-t^6) \\ n=6 $$ then $(1-t^6)^6 = \sum_{j=0}^{6} {6 \choose j} (1)^{6-j}\cdot{-t^{6j}}  \text{ but not } \sum_{j=0}^{6} {6 \choose j} (-1)^jt^{6j}$ .

Comment: Note that $(-t^6)^j=(-1)^j(t^{6})^j$

Comment: $\LaTeX$-only titles are discouraged. Edited.